# how can I use CSS to hover over an entire list element including the bullet?

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a simple list with bullets. I would like to change the color of both the bullet and the text when hovered over. Only the text change color and not the bullet. Here is the HTML and CSS:

```
<div id="navtop">
    <ul>
    <a href="calendar.html" > 
    <li>Calendar </li>   </a>   
    </ul>
</div>      




#navtop {
     float: right;
     width: 650px;
     font-size: 1.2em;
     padding-left: 30px;    
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    height: 65px;
}


#navtop ul {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 70px;

}

#navtop li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 280px;
}

#navtop a,  #navtop ul  {
    color: #ffd; 
    }


#navtop  ul a:hover ,   
#navtop ul a:active,
#navtop ul  li:hover,
navtop ul li:active 
{color:#f93; }

#navtop ul a:hover  li{
    color:#f93; }
```

Comment: As a first consideration, note that your [HTML is invalid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul). You can't make an `<a>` element a child of a `ul`. Wrap the `<li>` element around the `<a>` element (including the text), and you're good on that front.

Comment: I thought that might be the case. Please clarify why that is invalid code and where I can get more information.

Comment: The link to more information is embedded in my first comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve something similar to what you're looking for with CSS pseudo elements depending on the bullet style you want and if that can be achieved with a unicode character.

Using `list-style: none;` and replacing the bullets with CSS pseudo element content gives you control over the color.

I've put together a jsBin with a small example that might be able to help you out [here](http://jsbin.com/zuvoyasedu/3/edit?html,css,output).

You'll see in the example, I've colored the different list items different colors based on a class and then on hover each of them will show an orange bullet and text.

You can also run the following snippet;

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding   : 0;
}

li { 
    padding-left: 16px; 
    position: relative;
}

li:before {
    position: absolute;
    left   : 4px;
    content: "•";
}
li.is--red:before {
  color: red;
}
li.is--green,
li.is--green:before {
  color: green;
}
li:hover,
li:hover:before {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li class="is--red"><a>Some link</a></li>
    <li class="is--green"><a>Some other link</a></li>
    <li><a>Some other link</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Hope that helps you out!